# Where can I get the "Silverlight Developer Runtime" for Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight

The error I'm getting is:

> Unable to start debugging. The Silverlight Developer Runtime is not installed. Please install a matching version.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It depends what version you want - if you want v4 then [silverlight.net/getstarted/](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/) has a couple of download links. If you want v3 or before then you may have to ask on the forums.

EDIT: The link is currently titled "windows developer runtime"

Direct links:

- Windows Developer Runtime [v4](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188039) & [v5 Beta](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213904)
- MacOs X Developer Runtime [v4](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188040) & [v5 Beta](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=213905)

Answer (score 0):

The Silveright **5** Developer Runtime is available within the [Microsoft® Silverlight® 5 Tools for Visual Studio® 2010 SP1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=28358). It is listed under the Details section on that page.

Comment: Link is not working, either replace it or delete it.