# Where can I find the "Silverlight Developer Runtime" for Silverlight 5?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0, remote-debugging

I need to remote debug a Silverlight application that's running on a Mac. According to [Microsoft's walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903948(v=vs.95).aspx) I need to install the developer runtime on the Mac.

I've been Googling for a while now but I can't find an up to date version. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3232271/where-can-i-get-the-silverlight-developer-runtime-for-silverlight-4) has links to version 4 and a beta for version 5, but nothing for the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
[Silverlight 5 Developer Runtime for Mac OSX (32 bit)](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229325)

Comment: Thanks. BTW, where did you find the link?

Comment: Here: http://andrey.moveax.ru/news/2011-12-10/silverlight-5-released/. That blog is in my Google Reader.

Comment: Is there a 64 bit version?